# How to kill a process that have been forked?

Tags: c#, process, fork, kill

I'm trying to start a process, here calc.exe, waiting X seconds, and kill it:

```
Process p = Process.Start("calc.exe");
Console.WriteLine(p.Id);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
p.Kill();
```

When i execute this code, output give me the PID of the new process (e.g. 7152), BUT after sleep, the Kill() doesn't work, it says the process is not running anymore. BUT i saw the calc still running, i can use it.

When i look in details of task manager, the PID of calc.exe is not the same than the previous... why?

How can i kill the process i've created? (calc.exe is just an example, but it could be a.txt, b.word...)

Thanks and sorry for my english! :)

Comment: Have you read this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/50ecbcf2-d2d3-4f21-9775-5b8be1bd4346/how-to-terminate-a-process-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I _guess_ it may be similar to what MS Photo does. The Process you start _is_ in fact dead. Because it fires up another Process and hands over, then terminates itself.

Comment: It's probably specifics of windows 10 special apps, like 'calc'. If you change 'calc.exe' to 'notepad.exe' everything works as expected.

Comment: @langme yes i've already try like that:

`
foreach(Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("calc.exe"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
`

But the same error appears

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the pid changing? what happens if you compare it using

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName( "calc.exe" );
foreach(var proc in p)
    Console.WriteLine("Found: "+proc.Id == myExpectedProcId);
```

After you have the pid here is a hacky way to kill it

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Kill a process, and all of its children, grandchildren, etc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pid">Process ID.</param>
    private static void KillProcessAndChildren(int pid)
    {
        // Cannot close 'system idle process'.
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
                ("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid);
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            KillProcessAndChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
        }
        try
        {
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
            proc.Kill();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
          

  // Process already exited.
    }
}
```